# passing video frame to Core Image on osx

Tags: macos, avfoundation, core-image

Hi all you awesome coders! I've put together this thing from various helpful sources over the last couple of weeks (including a lot of posts from stackoverflow), trying to create something that will take a webcam feed and detect smiles when they occur (might as well draw boxes around the faces and the smiles as well, that doesn't seem like it would be hard once they are detected). Please give me some lee-way if it's messy code because I'm still very much learning. 
Currently I'm stuck at trying to pass the image to a CIImage so it can be analysed for faces (I plan to deal with smiles after the face hurdle is overcome).  As it is the compiler succeeds if I comment out the block after (5) - it brings up a simple AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in a window. I think this is what I've called "rootLayer", so it's like the first layer of the displayed output, and after I detect faces in the video frames I'll show a rectangle following the "bounds" of any detected face in a new layer overlaid on top of this one, and I've called that layer "previewLayer"... correct?

But with the block after (5) there, the compiler throws out three errors -

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments", referenced from:
>         -[AVRecorderDocument captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVRecorderDocument.o
>     "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
>         -[AVRecorderDocument captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in AVRecorderDocument.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and what my next steps are?

Thanks for any help, I've been stuck at this point for a couple of days and I can't figure it out, all the examples I can find are for IOS and don't work in OSX.

```
    - (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        // Move the output part to another function
        [self addVideoDataOutput];

        // Create a capture session
        session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

        // Set a session preset (resolution)
        self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

        // Select devices if any exist
        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if (videoDevice) {
            [self setSelectedVideoDevice:videoDevice];
        } else {
            [self setSelectedVideoDevice:[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeMuxed]];
        }
        NSError *error = nil;
        //  Add an input
        videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
        [self.session addInput:self.videoDeviceInput];

        // Start the session (app opens slower if it is here but I think it is needed in order to send the frames for processing)
        [[self session] startRunning];


          // Initial refresh of device list
         [self refreshDevices];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addVideoDataOutput {
    // (1) Instantiate a new video data output object
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    captureOutput.videoSettings = @{ (NSString *) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };

    // discard if the data output queue is blocked (while CI processes the still image)
    captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;

    // (2) The sample buffer delegate requires a serial dispatch queue
    dispatch_queue_t captureOutputQueue;
    captureOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("CaptureOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:captureOutputQueue];
    dispatch_release(captureOutputQueue);  //what does this do and should it be here or after we receive the processed image back?

    // (3) Define the pixel format for the video data output 
    NSString * key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
    NSNumber * value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
    NSDictionary * settings = @{key:value};
    [captureOutput setVideoSettings:settings];

    // (4) Configure the output port on the captureSession property
    if ( [self.session canAddOutput:captureOutput] )
    [session addOutput:captureOutput];

}
// Implement the Sample Buffer Delegate Method
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

// I *think* I have a video frame now in some sort of image format... so have to convert it into a CIImage before I can process it:

    // (5) Convert CMSampleBufferRef to CVImageBufferRef, then to a CI Image (per weichsel's answer in July '13)
    CVImageBufferRef cvFrameImage = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);  // Having trouble here, prog. stops and won't recognise CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer.
    CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
    self.ciFrameImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVImageBuffer:cvFrameImage options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments];
    //self.ciFrameImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVImageBuffer:cvFrameImage];

    //OK so it is a CIImage. Find some way to send it to a separate CIImage function to find the faces, then smiles.  Then send it somewhere else to be displayed on top of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    //TBW

}


- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    return @"AVRecorderDocument";
}


- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    // Attach preview to session
    CALayer *rootLayer = self.previewView.layer;
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES]; //aaron added
    self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
    [self.previewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack)];
    [self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
    [self.previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
    //[newPreviewLayer setAutoresizingMask:kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable];  //don't think I need this for OSX?
    [self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];
//  [newPreviewLayer release];  //what's this for?


}
```

Comment: Wow. I guess two days and one StackOverflow post is what it takes to figure out that I haven't added CoreMedia.framework to my project. The error doesn't appear anymore, now I have another problem - the program never gets to the block after (5)... I put a stop point there, which is never hit. Any ideas?

Comment: buuut... now it does get to there. No idea what I changed from 8 minutes ago (I don't think I changed anything) but now it successfully gets to the "convert to CI Image" step. Will keep you posted

Comment: Since you described your journey in such detail... would you care to spare the final words? did you get it to work? would you please enhance your Question/Answer and throw in working-order code? I am doing this myself now, and fail on other things . Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Motti - sorry about that, you are right in that I should share what I learned. Unfortunately I last touched this project over two years ago, so I don't remember it enough to troubleshoot stuff. But the whole project is on my GitHub repo still - you can find the relevant file at https://github.com/ajlowndes/SmileShutter/blob/master/AVRecorder/AVRecorderDocument.mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moved from the comments section)

Wow. I guess two days and one StackOverflow post is what it takes to figure out that I haven't added CoreMedia.framework to my project.